# How to solve $\mathbb{E} \left[ \log(1+X) \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-F_X(x)}{1+x}\,dx$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I would like to know how can I solve $\mathbb{E} \left[ \log(1+X) \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-F_X(x)}{1+x}\,dx$. Is there a paper I could refer to?

Comment: What do you mean by solving? For a non-negative valued random variable $X$, the equation in question is in fact an *identity*.

Comment: @SangchulLee Actually I don't know why the left hand side is equal to the right hand side. How can I show it is an identity? Can you show me the step by step derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since providing a more general result needs little extra effort, let us do so.

Let $g$ be a continuously differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ with $g' \geq 0$. Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) = 1$. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[g(X)]
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{X} g'(x) \, dx \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} g'(x) \mathbf{1}_{\{x < X\}} \, dx \right] \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} g'(x) \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{x < X\}} \right] \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} g'(x) \left(1 - F_X(x)\right) \, dx,
\end{align*}

where in the last step we used $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{x < X\}} \right] = \mathbb{P}(x < X) = 1 - F_X(x)$. Now your question corresponds to the case $g(x) = \log(1+x)$.

---

*Remark.* This proof works for *any* non-negative random variables and any such $g$, including the case $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \infty$. If in addition that $X$ is a continuous random variable, one can simply apply the integration by parts

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[g(X)]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) F_X'(x) \, dx \\
&= \left[ -g(x)(1-F_X(x)) \right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}
   + \int_{0}^{\infty} g'(x) (1 - F_X(x)) \, dx
\end{align*}

with an appropriate assumption on $g(x)$ so that $g(x)(1 - F_X(x)) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to further inquire does this work if if $X=\frac{Y}{Z}$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables.

Comment: @M.A.N, This literally works for *any* non-negative random variables, however they are constructed. So as soon as your choice $X=Y/Z$ is guaranteed to be non-negative, then you are good to go :)

Comment: Thank you for enlightenment. I will bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two sides is $$\int_0^\infty F_X'(x)\ln(1+x)+\frac{F_X(x)-1}{1+x}dx=[(F_X(x)-1)\ln(1+x)]^\infty_0=0.$$

Comment: @J. G. Thanks for giving me your answer. Is a new perspective to me. However, I don't understand how u obtain the first equality. Can you teach me how to obtain it? My problem is i don't know how to deal with the integration of a general pdf and cdf. So far, I suppose the second term is 0 immediately since it is the integration of a cdf. For a specific pdf and cdf, i think i can solve it.

Comment: @ I first wrote the mean as an integral of $f_X(x)\ln(1+x)$, $f_X$ of course being $F_X'$. The I subtracted one integrand from the other to express the difference between the two sides of your equation as a single integral. The rest is just the product rule.

Comment: @J. G. Oh ok !!! I got it now.. Thank you for your enlightenment.. By the way, if I somehow know my expected value (e.g. in some forms), can i just use this method to show that they are an identity. In other words, I don't really have to derive from the left hand side, step by step, to show that it is an identity. As long the difference is 0, they should be an identity and that should be sufficient for a proof.